# MySQL Query Caching (2)

Tags: mysql, caching

This is not a problem but it belongs to site optimization. I have 110K records of hotels. When I use SELECT something query it will pulled out data from 110k records.

If I search a hotel list with more than 3 star rating, price between 100 - 300 $ and within Mexico City. Suppose I got 45 matching results.

Is there any other way when I add more refinement, it will pulled out data from just only the 45 matching and not go with the 110K data?

Comment: What queries are you using? Show us some code

Comment: Maybe there is a different way rather than using `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`? But why? Which is the problem? If your database design is good your query should be pretty fast...

Comment: With the right indexes, sending the sql code only the right results come back so you could have 110,000k records, and say 5 come back.. and do so fast.. with the wrong indexes it comes back slow, with no where clause, they all come back and your local code has to do all the work

Comment: You should use `WHERE` and indexes. Show us your schema and your query, and we can help some more.

Answer (score 1):

The key is indexes my friend... make sure you have indexes of all items used in the WHERE and this will reduce cardinality when selecting...

On a side not... 110k rows is still an extremely small data set for MySQL so shouldn't pose much of a performance issue if you haven't got correct indexing on the table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is more depend on how often your data updates.

See.

1. [The MySQL Query Cache](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/390.cfm)
2. [Query Caching in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748637/query-caching-in-mysql?rq=1)
3. [Caching question MySQL or Filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433243/caching-question-mysql-or-filesystem?rq=1)

> I am saying that is there any other way when I add more refinement, it
>   will pulled out data from just only the 45 matching and not go with
>   the 110K data.

Then make view of those 45 rows and apply query to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using query

```
Create view refined as select * from ....
```

And after that add more select queries to that view
like

```
 Select * from refined where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, i tend to agree with [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11100235/620813), indexes matter.

1. Check what kind(s) of queries are most frequent, and construct multi-column indexes on the table accordingly. Note that the order of columns in the indexes does matter (as the index is a tree, first column appears in tree root, so if your query does not use that column - the whole tree is useless).
2. Enable slow query log to see what queries actually take long (if any), or not use indexes, so you can improve indexes over time.

Having said this, query cache is a real performance boost, **if your table data is mostly read**. Here is a [useful article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/) on mysql query cache.